# Changing state with body width change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to change state when I'm changing width of the document. How can I do it in React? Any suggestions how to get body element and using onChange on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onresize = () => this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first return 2 different view based on the screen size, you can get help from here:
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

then every time the screen changes (based on values you use on each view), componentDidMount will be called and you can change the state there.